# How do mask like this using Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop

[image]

Wood is a large image of wood, the red is what is shown. I have this on a PSD sent to me and I'd like to know how to do this to be able to add another texture as this would be amazing help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has not relation to photography. Maybe try googling clipping mask or search the [graphic design SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I did have this on Stackoverflow and they told me to post here...

Comment: LOL, those Graphic Design guys need some reality adjustment. This is far more the technical aspect of design than photography...

Comment: @TimMarshall Do you have a link to the StackOverflow question? I'll pop over and re-educate them :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Windows, hold left Alt key and click between layers - the top one will "clip" - just try, and you'll figure it out ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is called Clipping Masking, see [this link](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/clipping-masks-essentials/).